# How to add offline screen in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, mobile-development

hey I have created an app in flutter it has a download page just like youtube
what I want to do is when the app loads it should check the internet connection and if it is not there it should redirect the user to the download screen

```
    This is the error


    ../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_translate-3.1.0/lib/src/utils/device_locale.dart:11:49: Error: Property 'window' cannot be accessed on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
         - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
        Try accessing using ?. instead.
          final deviceLocales = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locales;
                                                        ^^^^^^
        ../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/percent_indicator-4.2.1/lib/linear_percent_indicator.dart:162:5: Warning: The class 'WidgetsBinding' cannot be null.
        Try replacing '?.' with '.'
            WidgetsBinding?.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        ../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/percent_indicator-4.2.1/lib/linear_percent_indicator.dart:162:30: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
         - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
        Try calling using ?. instead.
            WidgetsBinding?.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * Where:
        Script '/Users/samarthverulkar/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1102

        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
        > Process 'command '/Users/samarthverulkar/FlutterDev/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

        * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

        BUILD FAILED in 2m 1s
        Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a bool

```
bool internetAvailable = true;
```

Use internet connection checker [internet_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker)

```
InternetConnectionChecker().checkInterval = Duration(seconds: 10);
      InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen(
        (InternetConnectionStatus status) {
          switch (status) {
            case InternetConnectionStatus.connected:
              // ignore: avoid_print
              print('Data connection is available.');
              internetAvailable = true;
              setState(() {});
              break;
            case InternetConnectionStatus.disconnected:
              // ignore: avoid_print
              print('You are disconnected from the internet.');
              internetAvailable = false;
              setState(() {});
              break;
          }
        },
      );
```

Then based on the internetAvailable add the screens

```
return internetAvailable? Center(child:Text("no internet")):HomePage()
```

Comment: i dont know why after doing this I got this errorn

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: i have edited the question i have inserted the error

Comment: If you are running on flutter version less than 3 please downgrade the version of this package

Comment: lib/main.dart:27:11: Error: Setter not found: 'internetAvailable'.
          internetAvailable = true;

Comment: Add this variable `bool internetAvailable = true;` edited my answer too

Comment: help regarding one more thing  what to do about setState(() {});

Comment: This method check goes inside a stateful widget.